Is there a way to faster a Interpolation IDW done in python for a large array?
I have to do an interpolation on a data set of more than 11 thousand lines and 87 columns, which takes 1:40 minutes to complete. I've already tried using dask array and chunk list but it still takes a long time to finish running. Maybe I'm using the wrong dask array, could anyone help me?
I have a function that applies IDW interpolation, my sample data (known values), and the unknown values ​​are in the unknown_points array (11 thousand rows) that I am trying to apply the dask to. I am placing the result of the interpolation in my test_2 dataframe, according to the columns that were interpolated.
import dask.array as da

l = da.from_array(unknown_points, chunks=(100, 100))

columns = len(values[0]) #87 columns

for i in range(columns):
   
    interpolated_values = idw_interpolation(sample_points, l, values[:,i], power=2)
  
    teste_2[i] = interpolated_values



Hi, 11 thousand lines and 87 columns is not really big... I guess your computation is mostly compute bound, not sure Dask can really help there. (100,100) chunks are really small ones.
